# Is zxing accurate?

Tags: barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I'm developing an iphone and android app that uses very simple barcode scanning. We've narrowed our barcode type to 2D, particular either QR or DataMatrix.

I've written two quick and dirty apps using Scandit and Zxing (using mostly their sample code) to test and compare, and I've found Scandit to be so much faster in acquisition and decoding, but more importantly, far more accurate.

Disclaimer: For my tests, I was using online barcode generators and printing them on my laser printer -- not sure if that matters.

Question: Does this sound typical? I'd like to use Zxing given it's opensource support, but I'm concerned about it's reliability. Any insight into this, particularly the trustworthness of Zxing for QR and/or DataMatrix would be very appreciated!

Comment: it sounds like you're getting better performance with Scandit, so why is this a question?

Comment: Two reasons why the question: (1) Scandit is a commercial company, and charges depending on the plan, and I'd prefer an (active) opensource project, and (2) My results could be due to an error in my testing or lack of knowledge of Zxing, so I was trying to see if my experience was reflective of others.

Answer (score 0):

I would try scanning with Barcode Scanner to rule our your code. It represents how ZXing ought to work on an Android device.

If you can't scan QR codes very easily then something is wrong with the device. Try the device bug workaround settings.

DM is not as strong as QR codes. You should find it works though. again just try the app.

On a desktop this changes and you need to enable hints like TRY_HARDER. but not on mobile.

Comment: "IOS does not probably work as well." :-( QR code support in C++/iOS is comparable to Java.

Comment: I will strike it out, you're right that this shouldn't be a big difference. I was hoping to blame the difficulty in maintaining this port, which is truly hard, and not the original code nor the skill of the port-er.